# Refactoring for loop containing nested lists/dictionary

Tags: python, loops, refactoring

Question:  As part of my learning from this Python book I've been reading, one of the challenges is to refactor some code from a previous challenge.  The challenge is to refactor the loop that reiterates over the list 'all_eq_data' that contains data loaded into it from a JSON file.  The for loop that does the pulling uses 4 variables (mags, lons, lats, title) but the challenge states those variables are not necessary and that the loop can be reduced to 4 lines (and I assume to load data into corresponding lists).

So, just looking for a nudge in the right direction, at least.  I definitely want to get this before moving along to the next section of the book/project.  Thank you for the help!!

```
    ...
    import json
    from plotly.graph_objs import scattergeo, Layout
    from plotly import offline

    # Explore the structure of the data.
    filename = 'data/eq_data_30_day_m1.json'
    with open(filename) as f:
        all_eq_data = json.load(f)
    
        all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']
        # print(all_eq_dicts)
    
        eq_dict = []
    
    
    mags = [eq_dict['properties'] for 'mag' in all_eq_dicts]
    lons = [eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]  "lon" in all_eq_dicts]
    lats = [eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1] in all_eq_dicts]
    hover_texts = [eq_dict['properties'] in all_eq_dicts]
    
    
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Using the for loop to iterate over the data; refactor loop to reduce lines of code.
    
    # mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
    for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
        mag = eq_dict['properties']['mag']
        lon = eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
        lat = eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1]
        title = eq_dict['properties']['title']
        
        mags.append(mag)
        lons.append(lon)
        lats.append(lat)
        hover_texts.append(title)
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
# Map the earthquakes.
    # Using a dictionary to plot the data and allow customization.
    data = [{
        'type': 'scattergeo',
        'lon': lons,
        'lat': lats,
        'text': hover_texts,
        'marker': {
            'size': [5*mag for mag in mags],
            'color': mags,
            'colorscale': 'Viridis',
            'reversescale': True,
            'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
        },
    }]
    
# Visualize the data.
    my_layout = Layout(title='Global Earthquakes')
    
    fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
    offline.plot(fig, filename='global_earthquakes.html')
...
```

Comment: Could you perhaps include what `all_eq_dicts` is?

Comment: the variables just store intermediate results. You can avoid them by putting the results directly into the list: `mags.append(eq_dict['properties']['mag'])` - - that would shrink the loop to 4 lines. .... BUT - 8 lines is totally fine and may be more readable then cramming them directly inside.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your solution does not work

```py
mags = [eq_dict['properties'] for 'mag' in all_eq_dicts]
lons = [eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]  "lon" in all_eq_dicts]
lats = [eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1] in all_eq_dicts]
hover_texts = [eq_dict['properties'] in all_eq_dicts]
```

Because the for loops don't make anysense. What you have to do is to replace the strings with a variable. Just call it eq_dict and you should be good.

```py
mags = [eq_dict['properties']['mag'] for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts]
lons = [eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]  for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts]
lats = [eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1] for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts]
hover_texts = [eq_dict['properties']['title'] for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts]
```

Comment: I think `mags` and `hover_texts` need the keys otherwise they are identical lists.

Comment: True, thanks. I've updated that.